# How to override a property in application yml file from the functional testing module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two diff modules - application module and functional-test module. In application module's yaml file, we have property1 (used as a feature flag) set to true, while in functional-test module's yaml file, I want to set property1 to false, which will turn off part of the code. So is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a `application.yml` into your test-resources. Spring will pick it up - maybe you also need the `@TestPropertySource`-annotaion.
I think, it is the best way, because your test-config will not be shiped.

And the related docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

And a Baeldung tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source

Comment: This will not work. The application is a separate module and run using its yaml file. When the functional test module runs, it will interact with the service (application) which has already started and didn't know the purpose it's being started for (production run or functional testing)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate profile for tests and put the properties in test/resources directory

> src/test/resources/application-test.yml

Then you can activate profile by using annotation on test class

```
@Profile("test")
```

Comment: this will not work. As I said, they are two separate modules and the application booted regardless the functional testing project. What you described is more like a unit test case or functional testing in the same module.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment under one of the answers I understand that the tested application is already running when the (another) test application starts. In this case there is no way to implement a feature flag in the first application as a property. As properties will be loaded only once during the startup.

To implement a dynamic feature flag an external, accessible for both applications storage would be necessary. Like database, Redis, Aerospace etc.